# GLOB in SQL Server 2008 R2 - Reverse WildCard Search

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, glob

I have this problem where database column value has a regex as shown below,

MyTable

```
| ID | FileName |
| ---|----------|
|1   |  cft*.*  |    
|2   |  mst.*   |
```

And for this table I would like to write a query and that query should pick the following row if I use the filename "cft1015.txt" as a condition

```
| ID | FileName |
| ---|----------|
|1   |  cft*.*  |
```

is it possible and if it's how can I do it?

Comment: That looks more like [globs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) than regexes.

Comment: Thanks. Changed the heading. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: My mistake guys, just realized '*' can't be used for globs in SQL Server. Replaced '*' with '%' and everything works. Thanks

Comment: @user1345260 You should delete the questino or answer it your self then.

Comment: answering your own question (and accepting it) is acceptable here on SO. Please do so. (You;ll also be able to better format your answer *as* an answer because your attempt to include `*`s in a comment didn't work so well.